# Making a div transition slower into a new dimension with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I think a jsfiddle will illustrate the problem much better: http://jsfiddle.net/9mHk2/

I'm trying to get the wrapping div to transition into the new width with a slide/fade/something rather than snap into it.

What is the simplest way to do this?

```
<div style="border:1px solid #000000; padding:8px; float:right;">
    Here is a div with some text <span id="spn1">....</span>
</div>

<br /><br /><br />

<center>
    <input id="btn1" name="btn1" type="submit" value="Hide" />
</center>
```

```
$('#btn1').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#spn1').fadeOut('500');
});
```

Comment: what happened to the jsfiddle example after the question edit? now there is no code to reference :(

Comment: Someone edited the post to remove the code snippet. Can't have a jsfiddle link on a question without an accompanying code snippet. Unfortunately.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/9mHk2/

Comment: Post some of the code from the fiddle in the question instead of just `code`. =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you want to hide the ellipses and then slowly animate the rectangle, correct? You can do this by calculating the width before and after the `span` is hidden and then animate it:

```
$('#btn1').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    // Here's the width before the span is hidden
    var originalWidth = $('#rectangle').width();
    $('#spn1').hide();

    // Here's the width after the span is hidden
    var newWidth = $('#rectangle').width();

    // Now animate the difference!
    $('#rectangle').css('width',originalWidth).animate({width: newWidth}, 1200);
});
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/9mHk2/2/)

Comment: No problem. Happy Coding =D

Answer (score 0):

Here is a different approach than `user1506980`'s, hide the span using width animation. Requires some extra CSS.

```
#spn1 {
    overflow: hidden;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0;
    padding:0;
    height: 1em;
}
```

```
$('#btn1').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#spn1').animate({width:0},500).fadeTo(500,0);
});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DJDavid98/9mHk2/7/)